# Trying to format URL for Action using multiple params in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following action result:

```
        public ActionResult Index(int id, int? siteId)
        {
            //code here....
            return View(object);
        }
```

I have the following route mapping as follows:

```
       routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SettingsRoute",
            url: "Settings/{id}/{siteId}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Settings",
                action = "Index",
            }
        );
```

What do I need to do, so the url will be "Settings?id=1&siteId=133" instead of the format "Settings?id=1" durring initial load. Then to select a site it builds the URl "Settings/1/133".

I am using the following actionLink to create this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(site.Name, "Index", "Settings", new { id = Model.SettingsEnvironment.EnvironmentID, siteId = site.SiteID }, null)</li>
```

I can't seem to get the routing down right. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your optional URL parameter:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SettingsRoute",
        url: "Settings/{id}/{siteId}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Settings",
            action = "Index",
            siteId = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
```

ref: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/12/asp-net-mvc-2-optional-url-parameters.aspx/

Comment: I did that, and it still send to the following URL: "/Settings/1/1" instead of "/Settings?id=1&siteId=1". Why can I not use multiple params and have to sub them out in a path /1/1?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you're after. Why are you looking to use Querystring variables? URL segments are more typical in MVC to pass in parameters to your actions.

Comment: K. That is what I was wondering. So it is best and "standard" to use /{param}/{param}?  Then I will just forget the querystring params. That is why I am getting so confused by peoples answers on this routing stuff... lol    Thanks.

Comment: No worries. You can use querystring variables, but yes, typically URL segments are used.